# Puzzle. Transfer maximal coal using a train

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

We need to transfer coal from point $A$ to point $B$ using a train. There is $9000$ tonne at point $A$. The distance between point $A$ and $B$ is $3000$ km. Train can carry only $3000$ tonne included its fuel. Also train consumes $1$ tonne coal per $1$ km. How much coal can be transferred from point $A$ to $B$?

I can do only $1500$. But can't prove it is optimal.

Comment: You should see [Wikipedia on the Jeep problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep_problem)

Comment: This is exactly the same problem as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604871/jeep-problem-variant-cross-the-desert-with-as-much-fuel-as-possible except that the quantity of fuel and the distance have both been multiplied by 3. (It turns out the problem scales perfectly in that way, so the answer is exactly 3 times as much as the earlier problem's answer.)

Comment: A few months ago I too posted a mathematical puzzle on this site. I added the tags "recreational-mathematics" and "puzzle". Immediately several experts told that this was illegal. No puzzles are allowed on this site!!! My post was blocked and later on deleted. Please tell me why there is a different policy with regards to the puzzle by Ashot.

Comment: I don't know why your post was deleted. I have seen many puzzle questions here. Maybe policy has changed. You  may ask about it in meta
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are allowed to dump coal along the way and pick it up later.  You will leave $A$ three times, so will come back to $A$ twice.  The first depot should be where five trips burn $3000$ coal so you can leave twice going forward.  That means the first depot is $600$ km in and when you leave from there outbound the first time there is $3000$ on the ground and $3000$ on the train.  You want to leave the second depot with the train full and will make three trips between the first and second, so they should be $1000$ km apart.  You leave the second depot with $3000$ and burn $1400$, arriving with $1600$.